# Moving data from Javascript to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So, I'm trying to move data that I've acquired using javascript so that I can use it in PHP I'm getting data for when a user clicks on a certain div in my site, the code looks something like this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function recordClick(event){
    var x = event.clientX + $(window).scrollLeft();
    var y = event.clientY + $(window).scrollTop();
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var url = document.URL;
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {x:x, y:y, width:width, height:height},
                success: function(){
                  }
           });
}
</script>
```

For right now, I'm just trying to verify that I got the right data so my PHP looks something like

```
<?php
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];
    $width = $_POST['width'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    echo "<p>" .$x. ", " .$y. ", " .$width. ", " .$height. "</p>";
?>
```

I've confirmed that I am receiving correct data on the Javascript side, but on the PHP side all of the $_POSTs I'm calling are blank.  It's also worth noting that my reference to the AJAX API is in a different "header" file, but I can't figure out what's causing this.

Comment: pass the data as `data:  JSON.stringify({x:x, y:y, width:width, height:height})`

Comment: Are you checking ajax requests in the console window to see if any data is being sent/returned?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify()` while posting json data

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function recordClick(event){
    var x = event.clientX + $(window).scrollLeft();
    var y = event.clientY + $(window).scrollTop();
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var url = document.URL;
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify({x:x, y:y, width:width, height:height}),
                success: function(){
                  }
           });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Still nothing, is there some reference I need to implement to use JSON?

Comment: I tried it in phpfiddle, and it tells me that all of my $_POSTs, are undefined. But uhh, they technically are supposed to be undefined until the user clicks on the div. But even when I click within the <div> they are still undefined.

Comment: can you save it and share .

Comment: Sorry, I actually figured it out. There was an issue with my syntax

Comment: Please post your fix , let others also get benefited .